# Change style of UITableViewCell with Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableViewController subclassed to use as my search results controller. I have no storyboard or xib for it so it is implemented entirely in code. I have only implemented the data source methods.

I am trying to make the cells of the style `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` but cannot get this to work. In `viewDidLoad` I use the code `[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];`, then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I have this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```

However, given my `registerClass` call I don't think cell is ever nil so the style is never being changed from the default. If I remove the `registerClass` call I get a crash with the following message: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'. Removing the `if` block for cell has no effect.

This is such a small change I feel it shouldn't be necessary to subclass `UITableViewCell` or build it in Storyboard. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cell` will be never nil if you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`

Apple says:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

> `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered. If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil.
>
> `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the class or nib file you previously registered.

Try to do this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```

Comment: When you use **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:**, you should notice this
**IMPORTANT
You must register a class or nib file using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method.**

Comment: Awesome, thanks Klevison. This is the solution (along with removing the `registerClass` call in `viewDidLoad`).